# How to get access to property from another class without inheritance

Tags: ios, swift

I'm looking for solution for a little problem,
I've declared a button i an cell-class:

```
class MyCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var button: UIButton!
}
```

but now I'm trying to get access to the button variable from my main class, if the view is loaded the button should be hidden, and in several functions the button should be highlighted again:

```
class mainClassController: UICollectionViewController, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

    // here I try to create reference to the button variable
    ...
}
```

Comment: You should do that for every cell in the UICollectionViewDataSource

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess this should work(only tested in playground)

```
class MyCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    @IBOutlet var button: UIButton!
}

var myCell = MyCell()   //Generate one object of your class, just put this outside any class

class main: UICollectionViewController, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout{
    var cellButton = myCell.button
}
```

Comment: Yes sure!!! I'm such dumb, was thinking so difficult:))) Thanks Eric, it works fine:))