# How to change NSTextField value from another NSView (different swift files)

Tags: swift, macos, nsview, nstextfield

I have two different  *NSViews*.
 **viewA** is controlled from **ViewA.swift** 
 **viewB** is controlled from **ViewB.swift** 
 I want to change textField (*NSTextField*) that is in **viewB** from **viewA**.

i change it by creating an instance of **viewB** from **viewA**, but i get an error

Here is how i create the instance in **viewA**:

```
let myViewB = ViewB()
myViewB.changeValue = myString
```

And in **viewB** i declared:

```
var myString = "" {
    didSet {
        myNSTextField.stringValue(myString)
    }
}
```

This is the error I get when i change the *NSTextField* value:

> unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

UPDATE:

**file ViewB.swift**

```
class ViewB: NSView {
    ...
    @IBOutlet weak var widthTextField: NSTextField!
    ...
}
```

**file ViewA.swift**

```
 let myViewB = ViewB()

 class ViewA: NSView {
     ...
     if *statement* {
          ....
          myViewB.widthTextField.stringValue("try") // <- here i get the error
          ....
     }
     ...
}
```

Comment: I recenctly aswered a question like this here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35994684/how-to-get-access-to-property-from-another-class-without-inheritance/35995530#35995530

Comment: so I should but the `let myViewB = ChooseEdit()` outside of the class. But I get the same error.

Comment: no, you should generate one object of you CLASS (something like `var myViewB = viewB()` ) and then you can access viewB's property's in class a by doing `var textfield = myviewB.myNSTextField`

Comment: thank you for the answers, I'm doing it that way. but it still gives me the error

Comment: can you update the question and add all the code you have right now?

Comment: It looks like you're setting **changeValue** on **myViewB**, but your **viewB** class provides a variable named **myString**. Am I missing something? Is there any way you forgot to connect the IBOutlet for **myNSTextField** to the appropriate textField in your view?

Comment: no because changing the myNSTextField from it's class it works. @PaulVanWieren

Comment: @Eric I updated the code how I'm trying it.

Comment: You create a ViewB object but you're not doing anything that would connect a NSTextField object to the outlet.

Comment: @PhillipMills the NSTextField is connected via storyboard, I'm sure because if I change the value of it from viewB.swift everything works

Comment: But when you simply type ViewB(), you're not using the storyboard.

Comment: So i should create a NSTextField programmatically?  @PhillipMills

Comment: At the point you're trying to change the text, do you already have a ViewB object on the screen (or in existence, ready to be displayed)?  If so, use the one you have rather than creating a new one.  If you don't have one on the screen, create the new one to display using the storyboard.

Comment: That's what's happening. ViewA and ViewB load together because they're on a splitView. So I don't know for what reason it's not working. So answering, yes the NSTextField load's before trying to change the value @PhillipMills

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally fixed it! I create one variable which contains the text it needs to change it to like this: (using your test-project)

**In class ViewA**

```
    import Cocoa

var textToSet = "Hello"

class ViewA: NSView {
    override func drawRect(dirtyRect: NSRect) {
        super.drawRect(dirtyRect)

        // Drawing code here.
    }

    @IBAction func editPressed(sender: AnyObject) {
        textToSet = "No"
    }

}
```

**In class ViewB**

```
import Cocoa

class ViewB: NSView{

    @IBOutlet var myTextField: NSTextField!
    override func drawRect(dirtyRect: NSRect) {
        super.drawRect(dirtyRect)

        myTextField.stringValue = textToSet
        // Drawing code here.
    }

}
```

Comment: thank you, i needed a live update of the textFields (for now it can be ok). i Don't know why it's still not working in my project. I can't input anything in my NSTextField after doing this. I'll try it later on.

Comment: That's probably because you have disabled text-editing, that hasn't got anything to do with this

Comment: No. When i add `myTextField.stringValue = textToSet ` in my project i can't edit the textField. i don't know why. i commented everything in my code. still got this problem. i created another _NSTextField_, I still got this problem.

Comment: try adding another NSTextField and do the same thing as the other one. You get the problem even on the project I uploaded.

Comment: I got the problem. I have to add `override func controlTextDidChange(obj: NSNotification) { textToSet = myTextField.stringValue }` so the string gets updated. thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

In your code you generate a new object of the stringValue (I think). Does it work like this?

```
class ViewB: NSView {
    @IBOutlet weak var widthTextField: NSTextField!
}
let myViewB = ViewB()

class ViewA: NSView {
    if *statement* {
        myViewB.widthTextField.stringValue = "try" //setting it "try" without recreating the stringValue (done by "()")
    }

}
```

Comment: thank you for the reply. Same problem even with `myViewB.widthTextField.stringValue = "try" `

Comment: On which line does it crash? and what is the exact error? And if you put `widthTextField.stringValue = "try"` in class ViewA, does it work then?

Comment: yes it works. it crashes on the last line of your answer. I tried creating another project: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/43867401/editTextField.zip   when you launch the project expand the window to see both views.

Comment: I got it working in my new answer, using a workaround!